# Are there such sets $A, B, C$ that $A \cap B \neq \varnothing$, $A \cap C = \varnothing$, $(A \cap B) \setminus C = \varnothing$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My thoughts about that. There are two case:

1. $(A \cap B) \cap С = \varnothing$ but if $(A \cap B) \setminus C = \varnothing$ then $(A \cap B) \cap С \neq \varnothing$ and $(A \cap B) \setminus C \neq \varnothing$
2. $(A \cap B) \cap С \neq \varnothing$ but we have $A \cap C = \varnothing$ in this case $(A \cap B) \cap С = \varnothing$ because if $x \in A \cap B$ then a priori $x \in A$ but $A \cap C = \varnothing$ and it means $(A \cap B) \cap С = \varnothing$ hence $(A \cap B) \setminus C \neq \varnothing$

Comment: Enclose math expressions in dollar signs to have MathJax render the expressions.  `$A\cap B$` generates $A\cap B$ while just writing A\cap B doesn't render things.  Also, use `\emptyset` rather than `\varnothing`

Comment: As for the content of your question... draw yourself a venn diagram.

Comment: my 1 case is a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't such sets. Since $A\cap B \ne \emptyset$, the only way that $(A\cap B)\setminus C$ can be empty is if $A\cap B \subset C$. But this would mean that $A\cap C \ne \emptyset$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the proposed relations hold. Then we should have $A\subseteq C^{c}$, which means that $A\cap C^{c} = A$.

Consequently, we get that

\begin{align*}
(A\cap B)\backslash C = (A\cap B)\cap C^{c} = (A\cap C^{c})\cap B = A\cap B = \varnothing
\end{align*}

which contradicts the assumption that $A\cap B\neq \varnothing$.

Hence we conclude there are no sets $A$,$B$ and $C$ satisfying such relations.